# how to resize kendo grid after hiding a column?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, durandal

I have a condition in my kendo grid if true a column will be hidden :

```
self.resprecapcontratsGridOptions = {
            data: undefined,
            autoBind: true,
            scrollable: false,
            dataSource: self.resprecapcontratsGridDataSource,
            sortable: false,
            reorderable: false,
            serverPaging: false,
            serverSorting: false,
            serverFiltering: false,
            pageable: false,
            dataBound: function (e) {
                self.FixGridBindingAndHeaderScroll.apply(this, [true]);
                $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
                var grid = this;
                
                var lastURLSegement = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                if (!(Number.isInteger(parseInt(lastURLSegement)))) {
                    grid.hideColumn("eligibilite");
                }

            }
        };
```

The problem is when the column is hidden the columns of the grid get stuck to each other.The width of the columns get altered compared to the initial state.
I tried kendo grid methods read() resize() and refresh() but no luck.

Comment: Where did you try using the resize method? Can you share that code?